# Filter source data in Azure Data Factory (Data Flow) to get most recent values

Tags: azure-data-factory

I have the following data in my source:

[image]

I want to filter the data such that output will only include data with most recent date.
For example: DEF has 2 values 2.5, 3-Jan and 4, 4-Jan. I want rows with most recent date (4, 4-Jan) so that the output will contain the following result. How do I do that in data flow?

[image]

Comment: what's the source, csv or in SQL table?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I tried it successfully.Please follow the steps.

First step:
create a `source`(I used csv file with the data you provided),`RecentDate` column should be like '01-04-2020' rather than '04-Jan' because '04-Jan' can't be sorted.
The setting of Projection see the picture.

Second step:
create an `aggregate`, please choose 'Movie' column in the `Group By` configuration, and the setting of `Aggregates` please see the image.

Third step:
create a `new branch`(click '+' at the bottom right corner of source)

Fourth step:
create a `join` and setting please see the image.

The last step:
create a `select` and remove two duplicate column('Movie' and 'RecentDate') then output the `sink`.

Hope these can help you.

Below is all images:

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwWy1.png)

---

***Update Answer:***

Below is how to output only max rate:

This is my test data:

`Movie,MaxRate,RecentDate
ABC,3,02-01-2020
DEF,2.5,03-02-2020
DEF,4,04-01-2020
DEF,6,03-02-2020`

This is total flow image:

[total](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rmyln.png)

First step:create a source.The setting of Projection like this

[source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/woRjD.png)

Second step: create an aggregate, please choose 'Movie' and 'RecentDate' column in the Group By configuration, and the setting of Aggregates is below：

[aggregate](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8aa2.png)

Third step: create an aggregate, please choose 'Movie' column in the Group By configuration, and the setting of Aggregates is below：

[aggregate2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cbbFh.png)

Fourth step: create a join and setting please see the image

[join](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBHZa.png)

The last step: create a select and remove two duplicate column('Movie' and 'RecentDate') 
then name 'Rate' as 'MaxRate',finally output the sink.

Below is output:

`Movie,MaxRate,RecentDate
ABC,3,02-01-2020
DEF,6,03-02-2020`

If you want to output the min rate,just change the `max($$)` to `min($$)` in Second step.

If you want to output the both max and min rate, please do like above(max rate flow) until creating`select`finish and then `New branch` do min rate flow until creating `select` finish,finally join two select and delete duplicate column.

If you have another question,please let me know.

Comment: Thank you! What if I have the same 'Date' value? For example, RecentDate for both DEF rows is '1-4-2020'?

Comment: Do you need the max/min rate when 'Movie' and 'RecentDate' column are both same?

Comment: Can you please explain both scenarios? Outputting both max and min rates , outputting only max rate? Thank you!

Comment: Please see my update answer.Thank you.Any concern,please feel free to let me know.

Comment: If you think my answer helps you, you could mark it for answer.Thanks a lot.